# wrap label text in uicollectionviewcell in uicollectionview

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch

I have a uicollectionviewcell in a uicollectionview. This cell has a label that displays the data stored in an array.
As you'll know when the text of the label is too long for the cell it gets truncated.
I want to wrap the text of this label so that the entire text is visible in a particular cell. I tried the following code which works fine in uitableviewcell but not for a collectionview

```
cell.cellLabel.lineBreakMode=NSLineBreakByWordWrapping;
[cell.cellLabel  setNumberOfLines:0];
[cell.cellLabel sizeToFit];
```

Any insights and help on this will be highly appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

finally i got the solution for this. 
as i am using a CollectionViewCell , all the properties for label had to be set in the custom class extending UICollectionViewCell 
This finally did the trick.

Thanks everyone.

Comment: Can you expand on this?

Comment: set label properties on `awakeFromNib` of collectionViewCell subclass

Answer (score 1):

Inside your custom collectionView cell object, set your label's numberOfLines property to zero.

```
label.numberOfLines = 0
```

then in your constraints, pin your label on the leading and trailing anchor of the custom collectionView cells.

```
yourLabel.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: leadingAnchor),
yourLabel.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: trailingAnchor)
```